# Chrome mobile and Fancybox -> Images not loading correctly

Tags: responsive-design, fancybox

I have a website that aggregates some FB events for my city and I've tried making it responsive
I'm having an issue opening it in my phone(s3 mini) that the image for the event won't load correctly.. BUT it loads when I try closing that fancybox and opening the  a second time, this doesn't occur at all in desktop browsers.. I have no idea on how to fix this, can anyone help?

Address: fubuia.com.br

Here's pics:

**Opening an event for the first time**

[image: Opening for the first time]

**After closing fancybox and opening it again**

[image: After closing fancybox and opening it again]

Comment: It sounds like you might have a race condition on your hands - have you considered using the `.load` event handler to ensure the requested DOM elements have been fully loaded?

Comment: Include your code in the question so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

With some code it would be better...

I think the image is loaded after your fancybox, try to add `width` and `height` [properties](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_height.asp) in your images.

```
<img src="/path/to/your/image.jpg" alt="" height="100" width="100">
```